# Smart data extraction algorithm from websites

Tags: regex, algorithm, data-extraction

I'm building a deal aggregator so I need a crawler that will extract data from some sites: price, discount, image, coordinates and name of deal of cource.

Do you know of any tutorials, ebooks or something that will help me? For image and coordinates and discount I have a solution and pattern:

- image: biggest image is always the main image of deal
- discount: discount is always a number between 50 and 99 and always has a "%" symbol
- coordinates: is always in decimal numbers so I get it with regex

How do I get the following items?

- Name of deal?
- Price?

Do you know of any data extraction algorithms that can be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use XPath based scraper. For example [Web-Harvest](http://web-harvest.sourceforge.net/)

Or, if you want to analyze raw texts, I'd suggest using state-machine parser for recognizing templated parts of texts.

Look at this topic: [Are there APIs for text analysis/mining in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800509/are-there-apis-for-text-analysis-mining-in-java/6800681#6800681)

Comment: If you have access to html source of target sites, you can construct XPath expressions for scraper. You can do that because usually position of title, price, and other elements of text might been related to html tags

Comment: yes, i have about 10,000 sites (group buying) but i do not want to create a 10,000 scrapers for every site... so i need some unique solution for all that sites

Comment: as i say, i have solution for image and disscunt but for other element i dont have good solution

Comment: Look at state-machine parser for recognizing templated parts of raw texts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800509/are-there-apis-for-text-analysis-mining-in-java/6800681#6800681