# Java Joone analysis of html article

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, joone

I'm using [this article](http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/1546201/Using-JOONE-for-Artificial-Intelligence-Programming.htm) to try to understand the Neural network

I have a .txt file containing paragraph of pharases containing short stories with people names. I want Joone engine to identify subject of each paragraph with people names.

How accurate it can be done by AI and Joone engine? Any guideline is appreciated.

Comment: Do a lot of reading on (a) neural networks and (b) natural language processing before you even think about going down this path. You're in way over your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it may be some sort of offtop, but I'd propose you to use the Encog library for neural networks. Also, speaking of the txt file you have... well this is text analysis program, I don't think that this task would depend on the neural API you choose. For the text analysis libraries look over here, a good thread - [Java text analysis libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778388/java-text-analysis-libraries)